# How to make LoadData tag of liquibase case insensitive?

Tags: mysql, liquibase, loaddata

I have tsv file with column named USER_ID, but in by MySQL table it's column with the name user_id. So during loadData process of liquibase it can't map the column from .tsv file to the MySQL one since they are in different cases.
How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would take the simplest possible route and edit the TSV file to have the same column case as the database. If you have a need to do it on a regular basis, you could automate it with a sed script.